# Socket 10054 error while sending bitmap image in C++

Tags: c++, winsock

This is my Server Code :-

```
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET new_socket;
struct sockaddr_in server, client;
int c;
char *message = "Failed";


//Listen to incoming connections
listen(s, 3000);

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

while ((new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    puts("Connection accepted");
    int Size;
    char *Filesize = new char[1024];

    if (recv(new_socket, Filesize, 1024, 0)) // File size
    {
        Size = atoi((const char*)Filesize);
        printf("File size: %d\n", Size);
    }


    char *Buffer = new char[Size];

    //int len = Size;
    //char *data = Buffer;

    int Offset = 0;
    int Amount;
    while (Size > Offset)
    {
        if ((Amount = recv(new_socket, Buffer + Offset, Size - Offset, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
            MessageBox(hWnd1, std::to_wstring(WSAGetLastError()).c_str(), L"e", NULL);
            break;
        }

        if (Amount <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError();
            std::string aaa = Filesize;
            std::wstring aaa1 = std::wstring(aaa.begin(), aaa.end());
            MessageBox(hWnd1, aaa1.c_str(), L"e", NULL);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Offset += Amount;
            printf("2\n");
        }
    }

    FILE *File;
    File = fopen("out.jpg", "wb");
    fwrite(Buffer, 1, Size, File);
    fclose(File);

    free(Buffer);
    free(Filesize);

    InvalidateRect(hWnd1, NULL, FALSE);
    message = "OKAY";
    send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);

}
if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("accept failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    MessageBox(hWnd1, L"Fail", L"Fail", NULL);
}
MessageBox(hWnd1, TEXT("Connection Acceptedss"), L"Simple", NULL);

return s;
```

This is my Client Code:-

```
SOCKET s = client_control_mob(ipaddr);

WSADATA wsa;
struct sockaddr_in server;
char *message, server_reply[2000];
int recv_size;
std::fstream file, file1;
std::string line, ip;
std::wstring interface1;
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
int offset;
wchar_t wtext[120];
char* search = "";

//Send some data

FILE *File;
char *Buffer;
unsigned long Size;
capture_screen(hdc, hWnd1);

File = fopen("out.jpg", "rb");
if (!File)
{
    printf("Error while readaing the file\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

fseek(File, 0, SEEK_END);
Size = ftell(File);
fseek(File, 0, SEEK_SET);

Buffer = new char[Size];

fread(Buffer, Size, 1, File);
char cSize[1024];
sprintf(cSize, "%i", Size);

fclose(File);
send(s, cSize, 1024, 0); // File size

//int len = Size;
//char *data = Buffer;

int Offset = 0; int Amount;
while (Size > Offset)
{
    if ((Amount = send(s, Buffer + Offset, Size - Offset, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        break;
    }

    if (Amount <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Offset += Amount;
        printf("2\n");
    }
}

free(Buffer);
//Receive a reply from the server
if ((recv_size = recv(s, server_reply, 1024, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    puts("recv failed");
}

puts("Reply received\n");

//Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
puts(server_reply);

if (strcmp(server_reply, "OKAY") == 0){
    // Convert char* to LPWSTR
    mbstowcs(wtext, server_reply, strlen(server_reply) + 1);
    message = "OKAY";
}
closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();

message = "";
return message;
```

Server and Client recieve and send images to each other upto 1 or 2 minute after that I get 10054 error from server and everything stops down

I searched on net on 10054 error i got the result that server is stop sending the request to client or it has been shutdown how can i stop the server from shutdown and make it remain sending the request to client

Please help me how can i resolve this issue

Comment: I am not getting the winsock 10054 error when i am running this code on vmware while running this code with connection to wifi I am getting this error please help is this a hardware related issue